# ValueChangeListener problem

Tags: jsf

While calling the ValueChangeListener in JSF based on value change in dropdown, it is calling all the ValueChangeListner that are on that page.

There are two valueChangeListener in DataTable, while changing value in one dropdwon the 2nd one also executing.

```
<t:column id="avlId" styleClass="coltextcenteralign">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle['travelLocalAccommodation.title.availability']}" />
                    <h:outputText value="*" style="color:red" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </f:facet>
            <t:selectOneMenu value="#{accomDtls.availability}" immediate="true"
                valueChangeListener="#{TravelProcessingBB.localAccommodationBB.setAvailableFlag}" forceid="true" id="avl"
                onchange="return availabilityAlert('#{accomDtls.prepopulatedFlag}','avl[#{table_count}]')"
                styleClass="dropDownStyle" style="width:50">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Y" itemLabel="Yes" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="N" itemLabel="No" />
            </t:selectOneMenu>
        </t:column>
```

Comment: Could you add some relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

The value change alone won't automatically call the `valueChangeListener`. You need to submit the form as well. A commonly used "hack" is to call `form.submit()` using JavaScript during the `onchange` event. This will however submit the *entire* form. Truly the `valueChangeListener` will be triggered for all changed fields of the form.

To fix this in JSF 1.x, you need to hassle somewhat with the `immediate` attribute to skip all other form components from validating and with component `binding` so that you can properly get/set the other component's value. Long story short, I ever wrote an article about that: [populate child menus in JSF 1.2](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/10/populate-child-menus.html).

In JSF 2.0, this is however easier to achieve with help of `<f:ajax>` tag. If you're really using JSF 2.0 (your current question doesn't indicate that), then let me know if you need an example.